# Why do people put "captcha: x y" at the end of their posts?

Tags: discussion

I realize this isn't directly computer related, but I've ONLY seen this done on computer forums/message boards/comments. I see that some people write "Captcha: something xyz", as an example, after they write their post. What is this for?

I understand what a captcha is, but I do not understand why you need to put it in your post. Please explain!

Answer (score 6):

It's just a meme, and arguably a pretty dumb one.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a bit of fun usually to note an odd combination that has occurred. The Stack Overflow blog post *[Are you a human being?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/are-you-a-human-being/)* is an example of why.

Comment: Ah, the one post I never bothered to read.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes people will put it in the post when it is related to the content they are replying to or somehow funny.  You see this a lot on [TheDailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com) because they for some reason they seem to have more related and funny capchas than other sites.